# How to get date out of a cell containing the string "2017|03"?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is my data:

[image]

I am trying to build a `SUMIFS` formula to sum the sessions, if the **month = "last month"** (i.e., parsed out of these strings), and the **Channel Grouping = "Display"**.

Here's what I have so far:

`=SUMIFS(H3:H,F3:F,________,G3:G,"Direct")`

Since this is a string, not a date, I am not sure how to get it to match "last month".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not build up a string like this (or just hard-code it?)

```
=sumifs(H3:H,F3:F,year(today())&"|"&text(month(today())-1,"00"),G3:G,"Direct")
```

This builds up a string equal to "2017|03" by taking the year from today's date (2017) and one less than the month number from today's date which at time of writing is April so 4-1=3. The text function formats it with a leading zero. So the whole thing is"2017" & "|" & "03" which gives "2017|03" - this is compared against column F.

Note: January would be a special case (existing formula would give "2018|00" for previous month to January 2018 so would need a bit of extra code to cover this case and make it fully automatic).

By 'hard-code it' I mean just put 2017|03 in as a literal string like this

```
=sumifs(H3:H,F3:F,"2017|03",G3:G,"Direct")
```

then just change it manually for different months.

Here is a more general formula

```
=sumifs(H3:H,F3:F,year(eomonth(today(),-1))&"|"&text(month(eomonth(today(),-1)),"00"),G3:G,"Direct")
```

Just change the -1 to -2 etc. for different numbers of months.

**EDIT**

In light of @Max Makhrov's answer, this can be shortened significantly to

```
=sumifs(H3:H,F3:F,text(eomonth(today(),-1),"YYYY|MM"),G3:G,"Direct")
```

Comment: That works! I don't quite get what's happening here, but it gets the right answer. Also not following what you mean by "hard-code" it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I can't hard code it because I need my formula for last month, two months ago, and 13 months ago; it'll be different every month.

Comment: I will add more general formula to answer.

Comment: @Max Makhrov is right that I could have made the formula shorter by using =TEXT(TODAY(),"YYYY|MM") or in my case =TEXT(eomonth(TODAY(),-1),"YYYY|MM")

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add two more options:

## 1

This formula is slightly shorter and more powerrful, because it gives the full control over date format:

`=TEXT(TODAY(),"YYYY|MM")`

formula syntax is here:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en

## 2

In your case converting date to string is more efficient because it calculates one time in the formula, so there's fewer calculations. But sometimes you need to convert text into date. In this case I prefer using regular expresions:

`=JOIN("/",{REGEXEXTRACT("2017|03","(\d{4})\|(\d{2})"),1})*1`

---

**How it works**

- `REGEXEXTRACT("2017|03","(\d{4})\|(\d{2})")` gives 2 separate cells output:

  `2017    03`
- `{..., 1}` adds 1 to `...` and adds it to the right:

  `2017    03     1`
- `JOIN("/", ...)` joins the `...` input:

  `2017/03/1`

This looks like date, but to make it real date, multimpy it by 1:

- `"2017/03/1"*1` converts string that looks like date into a number `42795` which is serial number for date `2017 march 01`

Comment: You are right that your formula 1 is shorter than mine, also the Regex formula is potentially useful.